# to count the number of strings where the string length is 2 or more and the first and last character are same

Tags: python

Sample List : `['abc', 'xyz', 'aba', '1221']`

Expected Result : 2

```
def match_words(words):
  ctr = 0

  for word in words:
    if len(word) > 1 and word[0] == word[-1]:
      ctr += 1
  return ctr

print(match_words(['abc', 'xyz', 'aba', '1221']))
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The code seems to work. What do you want more ?\

Answer (score 1):

Store list values in ls

```
ls= ['abc', 'xyz', 'aba', '1221']
```

This code looping every item of list and storing each list item which satisfied given condition. the 'len' function taking the length of the output list.

```
len([x for x in ls if (len(x) >= 2 and x[-1] == x[0])])
```